# Globals not accessible from Vue template

Tags: vue.js

For example `{{ window }}` template gives out a `[Vue warn]: Property or method "window" is not defined`

Is this intended behaviour? If I understand correctly adding window to the Vue `data` would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is intended behaviour. The Template is "scoped" to the component instance, and there are only a few exceptions made - `{{ Math.random() }}` works, for example.

The `window` object as the global object is not something templates should directly interact with.

If you need to, use a method to get what you need.